# How do I use the rope from C++ STL in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, ropes

Apologies if I'm asking a silly newbie question. I'm new to C++ (familiar with C and objective C) and wanted to use the rope from the standard template library. Is this included with the libraries that Xcode uses? I have tried `#include <vector>` and the same for map successfully and also `ext/hash_map`. However rope does not seem to be available. Do I just have to download the source and include it in my project?

Comment: There isn't a `rope` in the standard C++ library. Why do you think there is?

Comment: I just searched "C++ standard template library" and got this https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html

Comment: Are there multiple versions of the 'standard' template library then?

Comment: This is a good starting point for what is in the standard library: http://en.cppreference.com/

Comment: @JohnP - The confusion (understandable) is between **a** standard template library, and **the** template library defined in the C++ standard. It doesn't get easier by the fact than large parts (but not all) of the STL got included in the language standard. Rope is one part that didn't get included.

Comment: The library "STL" was named years before C++ was standardised. As an indication of how ancient it is, the most FAQ is "Is the STL Y2K compliant?". (And there's no "standard template library" in C++, only the "standard library".)

Comment: Very good answer on STL and standard library : stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately "Rope" is not part of the C++ standard!

C++ Overview: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: How do I find what is in the standard? I have been looking at this: https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html which does include it.

Comment: Assuming you are you using llvm with libc++, here is your implementation http://libcxx.llvm.org. And updated answer

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted:

> This distribution of the STL consists entirely of header files: there is no need to link to any library files.

This means the steps to use it are:

- download the source code for SGI's STL implementation
- add them to your include path
- include files as necessary in your code
- compile

That said, the link you posted is not the C++ standard library. It is an implementation of STL, (the precursor to the C++ standard library) with a few (non-standard) additions. In particular, the rope implementation you found is a non-standard adition.

Comment: That statement applies if you use the SGI compiler, which is highly unlikely that the OP is doing.